# How to get rid of elastic scrolling on devices?

Tags: html, css, ipad, scroll, touch-punch

1. Main page with buttons and content which is having scroll to the page, click on one of the buttons on right side.
2. Full page cover or half page cover popup open.
3. After closing popup tried to scroll the page but unable to do it and content hiding behind / white page shows.
4. expecting screen 1 as its with scrolling.

How to get rid of elastic scrolling on devices?

[image]

Comment: How do we work on it if there is no code attached?